# Re-create this ejs view using Jade?

Tags: pug, ejs

I tried everything to include this ejs page to my Jade-based app but in vain. Now, I'm trying to re-create the same view using Jade. Does anybody know if there's an easier way to create templates using jade? Here's the page I'm trying to create:

[image]

Here's the rest of it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of html to jade convertors on the internet. So write the html an convert it.

Comment: Already have. Online converters give you error-laden versions. I'll give it another try though.